# Embedding A Matrix

Tags: matrices

Okay, I have a matrix $A \in M_k(\mathbb{C})$ that I want to view it as embedded in some larger matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, which means $k < n$, with zeros filling in the rest of the entries so as to make the dimension of $A$ "large enough" (i.e., equal $n$). For example, if $k = 2$ and $n =4$, then I have

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 A& \cdot &0 & 0 \\
\cdot & \cdot & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

but I could also have $k=3$, in which case the embedding becomes

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 \cdot& \cdot & \cdot&0   \\
\cdot& A & \cdot & 0  \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Pardon the lack of agreeable formatting. Is a more standard, more concise way of viewing this "embedding," perhaps even as a product of some sort (initially I had thought of a Kronecker product, but quickly realized that that would not work)?

Comment: I've edited your post along the lines of what I *think* you mean, feel free to roll it back (or ask me to do so) if I've deviated from your intended meaning.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you. That looks better than what I have. I just want to be clear, though, because I have a suspicion that the wording of my post is unclear: this is not a question about how to write such matrices in Latex, but rather about a better mathematical perspective on such a matrix. As I mentioned in my post, I initially thought of a Kronecker product (as well as a direct sum---only very quickly though!). So, if there was any confusion, hopefully that has cleared things up.

Comment: To me, a more logical ``embedding'' would involve filling in the new diagonal with $1$'s as such: $$ \begin{pmatrix} A & \cdot & 0 & 0\\ \cdot &  \cdot & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \end{pmatrix} $$ This way we can see the new matrix as a linear map $\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}^n$ that acts on a subspace of dimension $k$ according to $A:\mathbb{C}^k\to\mathbb{C}^k$ and fixes everything else.

Comment: @user193319 I understand that I have not answered your question, I just wanted to make the question clearer.

Comment: @Uncountable that makes sense, if you consider matrices as linear maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I see is to define 
$$A\mapsto I_{n,k}AI_{k,n},$$
where $I_{n,k}$ is the $n\times k$ matrix, where the top $k\times k$ block is the identity, and the rest is $0$, and similarly for $I_{k,n}$. But I don't know if you like this better.